# CMake using 32 or 64 compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, bulletphysics

I want to build the bullet physics source code for Visual Studio 2012 but I'm not sure if I have to use as compile Target Visual Studio 2012 or Visual Studio 2012 Win64.

Is the 32/64 referring to my OS or to the source I want to build?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Win64` refers to the target - if you set the generator to `Visual Studio 2012 Win64`, you'll be building 64-bit binaries.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with the 32x or 64x Version of my Visual Studio, right? That would mean that I have to choose the x32 version?!